# IPSec L2TP - Tunnel pass and handshake interval (Huawei router)

Tags: vpn, huawei-mobile-services, ipsec, l2tp

On the server, I installed the VPN using the "setup-ipsec-vpn" script of the hwdsl2 user. [I found him here](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn).

As a result of its actions, the script provided me with: *User name*, *password* and *IPsec PSK code*.

However, on the router, I have to put information about *Tunnel password*, *handshake interval* and *Authentication*. You can see the tab with the [router configuration here](https://www.expressvpn.com/support/vpn-setup/huawei-router-l2tp/). Unfortunately, I could not find such information (neither at Github nor on the server).

The router is a Huawei B525.

What can I do in this case? Do not complete these fields? Change some configuration in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LNS address:** IP (name) of the server

**Host Name:** Whatever

**Tunnel password:** IPsec PSK code

**Handshake interval:** 30s (`dpddelay` in [`vpnsetup.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/master/vpnsetup.sh))

**Authentication:** Can be "Auto"